# After destructuring assignment with 'let', can't I ressign a variable of them?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, destructuring

In practicing NestJS..

DTO is being used in Controller and I declared 3 variables for them by destructuring assignment.
At this time, I used 'let' keyword when declaring for a test.

```
export class SignUpDto {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  readonly password: string;
}
```

```
  @Post()
  async signUp(@Body() signUpDto: SignUpDto): Promise<void> {
    let { name, email, password } = signUpDto;
    console.log(1, name);
    if (!name || !email || !password) {
      throw new BadRequestException();
    }
    name = 'new name';
    console.log(2, name);
    console.log(signUpDto.name);
    await this.usersService.signUp(signUpDto);
  }
```

Right after declaration, 'name' has the value that REQ's body has.('username')
so I changed its value to 'new name'

and then 'name' variable printed 'new name' in console when I log only 'name' variable.
But, when I log 'signUpDto.name', it still prints 'username'.

```
// console.log(1, name);
1 username

// console.log(2, name);
2 new name

// console.log(signUpDto.name);
username

// the result returned from usersService
UsersService { name: 'username', email: 'user@email.com', password: 'PassWord' }
```

I've read official documents but I couldn't find a correct reason.

One of my idea is that they were stored in different locations in a memory so they prints different values.

Could you let me know what this does mean?
I don't know why 'name's value isn't changed..

Comment: `let name = signUpDto.name` creates a separate variable (value copied from the original), so whatever you do afterwards to `name` won't affect `signUpDto`.

Comment: Typescript is a superset of JavaScript so the JavaScript assignment rules apply here. If you do want to go down the rabbit hole the assignment operator is defined [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-assignment-operators) and the destructuring assignment  [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-runtime-semantics-destructuringassignmentevaluation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you destructure the object out via the `let { name } = body` you are creating a new variable named `name`. This value is a accessed by value, not by reference, so when you modify it, it does not modify the original objects value too.

Comment: @Ramsey if this answers you question, mart it as answer (green tick near voting)